# Hypothesis Testing with limited resolution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, measurement-error

Assume two univariate, normal distributions e.g. A~N(x,0,1) and B~N(x,1,1).

Assume that we receive a value e.g. t=0.2 (e.g. via measurements)
We want to perform hypothesis testing and decide if t belongs to distribution A or distribution B.
We can compute N(0.2,0,1) and N(0.2,1,1) and use the maximum likelihood estimator to decide.

Reduced resolution case:
Now assume that the value that we receive is t=0.2 with known error e, i.e. its range is in the interval [0.2-e , 0.2+e]. The error e occurs due to limited resolution of the measurement device.
I can directly proceed and compute the effect of the error e on the type I and II errors

Questions: Is this the correct way to model the error due to imprecise measurements? Is the measurement interval [0.2-e , 0.2+e] uniform ?
Are there any concepts/ideas/models that can be used for such situations?
Can the error e can be already integrated within the variances of distributions A and B? (to avoid the extra layer of complexity)